# VBA: Data transformation

Tags: vba, excel, etl

I have a CSV file with data in the following format:

```
ID,Var1.1|var2.1|var3.1,var1.2|var2.2|var3.2,...,Var1.n|var2.n|var3.n
```

where `ID` is unique by row and `n` varies with each row.

I would like to transform it in VBA to the following format:

```
ID,Var1.1,var2.1,var3.1
ID,Var1.2,var2.2,var3.2     
.    
.    
.    
ID,Var1.n,var2.n,var3.n
```

Manually, what I've been doing is importing the data into excel and transposing the piped vars, then splitting them using 'text to columns' functionality. Following this I've taken the top entry from the transposition and pasted it n times in a column to the left of the split data.

Any idea how to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sIn As String
Dim sOut As String
Dim sc() As String
Dim sp() As String
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject: Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Dim txsIn As TextStream
Dim txsOut As TextStream

Set txsIn = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\mydir\testIn.txt", ForReading)
Set txsOut = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\mydir\testOut.txt")

Do Until txsIn.AtEndOfStream
    sIn = txsIn.ReadLine 
    sc = Split(sIn, ",")
    For i = 1 To UBound(sc) ' element 0 contains the ID
        sp = Split(sc(i), "|")
        sOut = sc(0) ' ID
        For j = 0 To UBound(sp)
            sOut = sOut & "," & sp(j) ' varX.X
        Next j
        txsOut.WriteLine sOut
    Next i
Loop
' testOut.txt now contains the desired output
```

The above requires setting a reference as follows: Tools > References... > set checkmark next to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

If you don't want to set a reference, use late binding. Replace the last 3 `Dim` lines with these:

```
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim txsIn As Object
Dim txsOut As Object
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the warm welcome! Having run the code, it does almost exactly what I want it too (the splitting and transposition is great!) The only issue was that a line was output for each comma per line. As it was a csv file, it would output the ID column n times where n is the number of commas. Frequently you'd have a very small number of triplets which caused an issue. This was fixed by only outputing if the element of the array was non-empty. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, and that you fixed it by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already doing this manually then you can simply have excel record the VBA for you. Once you open excel hit "record macro" from the developer tab. Then complete all the steps you are doing manually, then hit stop recording.

After this point you can re-run the macro to check operation or click "edit macro" to launch the VBA editor and clean up the code. This should give you a very good base of VBA code to work with.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but ran into some difficulties passing a variable argument to the 'destination' parameter of the split cell function. Thanks all the same!